# Magento 2: How to send ID of checked insertListing grid to save data controller

Tags: admin, uicomponent, insertlisting

I have created a insertListing grid inside fieldset, Now I want to save id of checked grid items inside my custom collection field news_ids

I get this data in save controller params

[image]

But I am not getting this Listing item ids in save controller params

[image]

I am using insertListing below code, I don't know what problem occurs here

```
<insertListing name="testListingInsert">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="autoRender" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="ns" xsi:type="string">vtn_newsticker_listing</item>
                        <item name="externalProvider" xsi:type="string">vtn_newsticker_listing.vtn_newsticker_listing_data_source</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="news_ids" xsi:type="string">${ $.provider }:data.news_ids</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="exports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="news_ids" xsi:type="string">${ $.externalProvider }:params.news_ids</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </insertListing>
```

This is namespace for form

```
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">vtn_newsticker_group_edit</item>
        </item>
```

And I am using this fieldset for getting grid

```
<fieldset name="assign_news">
            <settings>
                <collapsible>true</collapsible>
                <label translate="true">News in Group</label>
            </settings>
            <container name="news_ids_container" sortOrder="160">
                <htmlContent name="html_content">
                    <block name="assignnews" class="Vtn\NewsTicker\Block\Adminhtml\Newsids\AssignNews"/>
                </htmlContent>
            </container>
        </fieldset>
```

Below is code of this file `Vtn\NewsTicker\Block\Adminhtml\Newsids\AssignNews`

```
<?php
namespace Vtn\NewsTicker\Block\Adminhtml\Newsids;

class AssignNews extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{
   /**
     * Block template
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'newsgroup/assign_news.phtml';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product
     */
    protected $blockGrid;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $registry;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface
     */
    protected $jsonEncoder;

    /**
     * @var Vtn\NewsTicker\Model\GroupFactory $groupFactory
     */
    protected $groupFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        \Vtn\NewsTicker\Model\GroupFactory $groupFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->jsonEncoder = $jsonEncoder;
        $this->groupFactory = $groupFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getBlockGrid()
    {
        if (null === $this->blockGrid) {
            $this->blockGrid = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                \Vtn\NewsTicker\Block\Adminhtml\Group\Tab\News::class,
                'news.grid'
            );
        }
        return $this->blockGrid;
    }

    /**
     * Return HTML of grid block
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGridHtml()
    {
        return $this->getBlockGrid()->toHtml();
    }
    
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    //public function getNewsJson() {

    //    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
     //   $groupFactory = $this->groupFactory->create()->load($id);
        
      //  if (isset($groupFactory)) {
      //      $result = $groupFactory['id'];
      //      $result = explode(',', $result);
       //     return $this->jsonEncoder->encode($result);
       // }
       // return '{}';
    //}


public function getNewsJson()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $groupNewsId = $this->groupFactory->create()
                                          ->getCollection()
                                          ->addFieldToFilter('id',$id)
                                          ->getColumnValues('news_ids');
        
        if (!empty($groupNewsId)) {
            return $this->jsonEncoder->encode($groupNewsId);
        }
        return '{}';
    }
    }
```

Below code of `Vtn\NewsTicker\Block\Adminhtml\Group\Tab\News`

```
<?php
namespace Vtn\NewsTicker\Block\Adminhtml\Group\Tab;
    
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class News extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    /**
     * @var Vtn\NewsTicker\Model\GroupFactory $newsFactory
     */
    protected $newsFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper
     * @param \Vtn\NewsTicker\Model\GroupFactory $newsFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Vtn\NewsTicker\Model\NewsFactory $newsFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->newsFactory = $newsFactory;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('group_news');
        $this->setDefaultSort('id');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->newsFactory->create()->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            'in_news',
            [
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'name' => 'in_news_ids',
                'values' => $this->_getSelectedNews(),
                'index' => 'id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-select col-massaction',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-select col-massaction'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'id',
            [
                'header' => __('ID'),
                'sortable' => true,
                'index' => 'id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'news_content', 
            [
                'header' => __('News'), 
                'index' => 'news_content'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'status', 
            [
                'header' => __('Active'), 
                'index' => 'status',
                'type'=>'options',
                'options' => array('1' => 'Yes', '0' => 'No')
            ]
        );
        
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('newsticker/group/edit', ['_current' => true]);
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _getSelectedNews()
    {
        $news = $this->getRequest()->getPost('selected_news');
        return $news;
    }
}
```

Below is phtml code `Vtn\NewsTicker\view\adminhtml\templates\newsgroup\assign_news.phtml`

```
<?php
/** @var \Vtn\NewsTicker\Block\Template $block */

/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\AssignProducts $block */
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product $blockGrid */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Helper\SecureHtmlRenderer $secureRenderer */

$blockGrid = $block->getBlockGrid();
$gridJsObjectName = $blockGrid->getJsObjectName();

?>
<?= $block->getGridHtml() ?>
<input type="hidden" name="news_ids" id="in_news_ids" data-form-part="vtn_newsticker_group_edit" value="" />

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Vtn_NewsTicker/js/newsgroup/assign-news": {
                "selectedNews":  <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getNewsJson() ?>,
                "gridJsObjectName": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ '"' . '$gridJsObjectName' . '"' ?: '{}' ?>
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<script>
    require('mage/apply/main').apply();
</script>
```

Below is assign_news.js

```
    define([
    'mage/adminhtml/grid'
], function () {
    'use strict';

    return function (config) {
        var selectedNews = config.selectedNews,
            categoryNews = $H(selectedNews),
            gridJsObject = window[config.gridJsObjectName],
            tabIndex = 1000;
        /**
         * Show selected news when edit form in associated news grid
         */
        $('in_news_ids').value = Object.toJSON(categoryNews); // add your hidden field id
        /**
         * Register Category Product
         *
         * @param {Object} grid
         * @param {Object} element
         * @param {Boolean} checked
         */
        function registerCategoryNews(grid, element, checked) {
            if (checked) {
                if (element.positionElement) {
                    element.positionElement.disabled = false;
                    categoryNews.set(element.value, element.positionElement.value);
                }
            } else {
                if (element.positionElement) {
                    element.positionElement.disabled = true;
                }
                categoryNews.unset(element.value);
            }
            $('in_news_ids').value = Object.toJSON(categoryNews); // add your hidden field id
            grid.reloadParams = {
                'selected_news[]': categoryNews.keys()
            };
        }

        /**
         * Click on news row
         *
         * @param {Object} grid
         * @param {String} event
         */
        
        function categoryNewsRowClick(grid, event) {
            var trElement = Event.findElement(event, 'tr'),
                eventElement = Event.element(event),
                isInputCheckbox = eventElement.tagName === 'INPUT' && eventElement.type === 'checkbox',
                isInputPosition = grid.targetElement &&
                    grid.targetElement.tagName === 'INPUT' &&
                    grid.targetElement.name === 'position',
                checked = false,
                checkbox = null;

            if (eventElement.tagName === 'LABEL' &&
                trElement.querySelector('#' + eventElement.htmlFor) &&
                trElement.querySelector('#' + eventElement.htmlFor).type === 'checkbox'
            ) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                trElement.querySelector('#' + eventElement.htmlFor).trigger('click');

                return;
            }

            if (trElement && !isInputPosition) {
                checkbox = Element.getElementsBySelector(trElement, 'input');

                if (checkbox[0]) {
                    checked = isInputCheckbox ? checkbox[0].checked : !checkbox[0].checked;
                    gridJsObject.setCheckboxChecked(checkbox[0], checked);
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Change news position
         *
         * @param {String} event
         */
        function positionChange(event) {
            var element = Event.element(event);

            if (element && element.checkboxElement && element.checkboxElement.checked) {
                categoryNews.set(element.checkboxElement.value, element.value);
                $('in_news_ids').value = Object.toJSON(categoryNews); // add your hidden field id
            }
        }

        /**
         * Initialize category news row
         *
         * @param {Object} grid
         * @param {String} row
         */
        function categoryNewsRowInit(grid, row) {
            var checkbox = $(row).getElementsByClassName('checkbox')[0],
                position = $(row).getElementsByClassName('input-text')[0];

            if (checkbox && position) {
                checkbox.positionElement = position;
                position.checkboxElement = checkbox;
                position.disabled = !checkbox.checked;
                position.tabIndex = tabIndex++;
                Event.observe(position, 'keyup', positionChange);
            }
        }

        gridJsObject.rowClickCallback = categoryNewsRowClick;
        gridJsObject.initRowCallback = categoryNewsRowInit;
        gridJsObject.checkboxCheckCallback = registerCategoryNews;

        if (gridJsObject.rows) {
            gridJsObject.rows.each(function (row) {
                categoryNewsRowInit(gridJsObject, row);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer to your question, I will describe how the category backend form handles the problem you are trying to resolve. I am confident if each part of the description I make below are clear with you, then you will see what is the problem in your code.

To start, I suggest you may first open the following file:

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml
```

Particularly, both areas below:

```
<settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="save" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\SaveButton"/>
            <button name="delete" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\DeleteButton"/>
        </buttons>
        <namespace>category_form</namespace>
        <dataScope>data</dataScope>
        <deps>
            <dep>category_form.category_form_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
```

--> in this area, the **namespace** will be the name of your form that will get posted to your controller. Therefore, the input field that will capture your table value will need to use this namespace

Second area to check below:

```
<fieldset name="assign_products" sortOrder="40">
        <settings>
            <collapsible>true</collapsible>
            <label translate="true">Products in Category</label>
        </settings>
        <container name="assign_products_container" sortOrder="160">
            <htmlContent name="html_content">
                <block name="gallery" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\AssignProducts"/>
            </htmlContent>
        </container>
    </fieldset>
```

--> this area will tell you what draws the table. It is likely you already know this part but I see this as an important point here

then, you also might want to check the file:

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/category/edit/assign_products.phtml
```

--> **this template is the nerd of our problem I believe**: you will find a hidden field and the value for **data-form-part** needs to match the **namespace** I mention above.

and finally:

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/web/catalog/category/assign-products.js
```

--> this file feeds the hidden input and I suspect you got this already

UPDATED ANSWER:
In your answer, this line should be `"gridJsObjectName": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ '"' . '$gridJsObjectName' . '"' ?: '{}' ?>`
should be

```
"gridJsObjectName": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ '"' . $gridJsObjectName . '"' ?: '{}' ?>
```

Also, the code that displays the table is:

```
<fieldset name="assign_products" sortOrder="40">
        <settings>
            <collapsible>true</collapsible>
            <label translate="true">Products in Category</label>
        </settings>
        <container name="assign_products_container" sortOrder="160">
            <htmlContent name="html_content">
                <block name="gallery" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\AssignProducts"/>
            </htmlContent>
        </container>
    </fieldset>
```

whereas your code uses a node `<insertListing..`

Finally, your node where you define the namespace is also different to the file `category_form.xml`

```
 <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="save" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\SaveButton"/>
            <button name="delete" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\DeleteButton"/>
        </buttons>
        <namespace>category_form</namespace>
        <dataScope>data</dataScope>
        <deps>
            <dep>category_form.category_form_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
```

Your code may be not having problem as it is. However, the one I did try on my local is as per my above comments and of course this is what I can help you with. Good luck

UPDATE: I have written a backend screen that shows a finished table that propagates the table data to the controller. the repository is public and you can use it to troubleshoot your issue: [backend screen repo](https://bitbucket.org/magstaging/backend-screen-with-table/src/master/)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation I have done this yesterday but not getting selected values in thehidden field, I didn't get the issue

Comment: I updated my question as per grid is showing in form but selected items id is not getting in db

Comment: this line should be "gridJsObjectName": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ '"' . '$gridJsObjectName' . '"' ?: '{}' ?>

Comment: Actually I am getting data from db in hidden values, I want selected value get update on select in values

Comment: good, so your problem is more than likely the namespace

Comment: Issue is with js file not with namespace, Can you please have a look "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'checkboxCheckCallback' of undefined"

Comment: I had the same error: what I did is clone first category product assigner widget and then gradually made it using my own customisations.. You are very close, but it is not really possible to debug without having the full module.

Comment: Okay I am going through errors

Comment: I noticed you have removed some of the original functions from the blocks.. The one particularly that reads from the registry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123503/discussion-between-herve-tribouilloy-and-arun-kumar).